# Azure IoT DPS - Enrollment Group - Create Or Update - Rest API

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk, azure-rest-api, azure-iot-dps

It Seems Rest API calls are not working for Azure - DPS Enrollment group. No response from the API call in the postman.

Followed the below URL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/service/enrollment-group/create-or-update?view=rest-iot-dps-service-2021-06-01

If you're able to execute REST API call then, Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to generate a security token for Service API authentication. You can find the sample needed to generate token from article [Service API authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-control-access#service-api-authentication). Here is the sample I have tested for my token generation.

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from hashlib import sha256
from time import time
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, urlencode
from hmac import HMAC
import requests
import json


def main():
    ttl = time() + 3600
    uri = '{yourdpsservicename}.azure-devices-provisioning.net/enrollmentGroups'
    sign_key = ("%s\n%d" % ((quote_plus(uri)), int(ttl))).encode('utf-8')
    #sign_key = "%s\n%d" % ((quote_plus(uri)), int(ttl))
    print(sign_key)
    signature = b64encode(HMAC(b64decode('key'), sign_key, sha256).digest())

    rawtoken = {
        'sr' :  uri,
        'sig': signature,
        'se' : str(int(ttl)),
        'skn' : 'provisioningserviceowner'
    }

    print('SharedAccessSignature ' + urlencode(rawtoken))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> Please ensure to replace your DPS service name in the URI and the key value in the signature

You should get a signature similar to below value.

[image]

Add this token to the postman `Authorization` header. Find the below image for reference.

[image]

The API also requires you to pass Attestation mechanism for your enrollment. I have tested the API call using Symmetric Key attestation by passing the keys as following in the request body

[image]

As you can see, the API returns `200 OK` response and gives details on the Enrollment group. The created enrollment group can be validated from the Azure portal DPS Manage Enrollments tab.

[image]

Hope this helps!